# dojo tree: click events problems

Tags: dojo

I can't get to click in a tree node. This the script:

```
 dojo.connect(tree_obj, 'onClick', function(item, node, evt){


                console.log('node: ' +tree_obj.getLabel(node));
                console.log('event: ' +tree_obj.getLabel(evt));
                console.log('identifier: ' + tree_obj.getLabel(item))

            });
```

this show console log:

```
 node: undefined
 event: undefined
 identifier: ETD 81
```

The tree structure:

```
     root (it's hide)
         node ------> 'undefined' in log on click
            item ----> I can get the label on click
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to Stackoverflow.

You cannot do `getLabel(evt)` or `getLabel(node)`. What did you expect this to return? If you simply want the event or node objects, just use them directly.

```
dojo.connect(tree_obj, 'onClick', function(item, node, evt)
{
    console.log("Item", item); // This gives you the object in your store
    console.log("Node", node); // This gives you the dijit widget object (UI)
    console.log("Event", evt); // This gives you the event object
    console.log('identifier: ' + tree_obj.getLabel(item)); 
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nZV98/6/